# SQL: How to select the record with the most recent past date for every record on other table

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

How can I reformulate this two queries in one single query on MySQL?

```
SELECT * FROM tvnetwork  
//this query gives me a list of TV networks
```

But networks usually change names and logos, so for each of the retrieved TV networks:

```
SELECT name, logo FROM tvnetworkinfo 
  WHERE id = $tvnetwork.id 
  AND date_since < NOW()
    ORDER BY date_since desc LIMIT 1

//this one gives me the most recent logo and name for the network
```

I intentionally leave out the NEXT name/logo change.  E.g. I want "NatGeo" instead of the old "National Geographic", but I also want "SciFi" instead of the not yet implemented "SyFy".

I'd like to retrieve everything in a single query.  ¿Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you really want every other record? That would imply that every network has exactly two records. Perhaps you want either the oldest or newest record for each network?

Comment: I need the newest (but not future) record from tvnetworkinfo, along with the corresponding tvnetwork record.

Answer (score 4):

To get the most recent list of network names & logos, use:

```
SELECT x.name,
       x.logo
  FROM (SELECT tni.name,
               tni.logo
               CASE 
                 WHEN @name = tni.name THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := 1
               END AS rank
               @name := tni.name
          FROM TVNETWORKINFO tni
       -- JOIN TVNETWORK tn ON tn.id = tni.id
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @name := '') r
         WHERE tni.date_since < NOW()
      ORDER BY tni.name, tni.date_since DESC) x
 WHERE x.rank = 1
```

I disregarded the JOIN to the `TVNETWORK` table, it didn't seem to be necessary to the output.  Uncomment it by removing the double hyphen before it in the query I provided.

Comment: +1, after it was abundantly clear some time ago after testing that my favorite `LEFT JOIN` & `IS NULL` approach is quite a bit slower :(