# Calculate the longest winning/losing streak for a user

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've already managed to make this to work but need help on improving the query and optimize it for fetching more parameters.

The query will calculate the longest streak for winning and losing a game and so far I've managed to make this to work by fetching win and lose as separate query's. But i would like to fetch them both at once. How can i make that to work by building further on this query (this one will calculate the longest win streak) :

```
SELECT MIN( c.ID ) - a.ID + 1 as Streak
    FROM games AS a
    LEFT JOIN games AS b ON a.ID = b.id + 1 AND b.P1Outcome= 'win'
    LEFT JOIN games AS c ON a.ID <= c.id AND c.P1Outcome= 'win'
    LEFT JOIN games AS d ON c.ID = d.id - 1 AND d.P1Outcome= 'win'
    WHERE
      a.UsrID = x
      AND a.P1Outcome= 'win'
      AND b.ID IS NULL
      AND c.ID IS NOT NULL
      AND d.ID IS NULL
    GROUP BY a.ID
    ORDER BY Streak
```

ID = The primary key on each game

P1Outcome = The users outcome on the game

UsrID = The users ID

First of all can there be any improvements and if possible can it also fetch the lose streak at the same time? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Table creation and sample data would help...I don't think this query should work - the b.ID is null and d.ID is null clauses should cause it to blow up, and you're not joining on UsrID anywhere..

Comment: You can probably use user variables to do this more efficiently. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755590/sql-how-to-select-the-record-with-the-most-recent-past-date-for-every-record-on/3755688#3755688 (@Andriy - Beat my similar comment by a few seconds there!)

Comment: @Martin: Haha, while I was struggling with my English, you took your time more productively and eventually was able to come up with something more material than my lamenting. Thank you, I can now remove my miserable attempt at being helpful. :)

Comment: I realize this question is a bit old now, and although not exactly MySQL, the example and walk through here are very good and answered my question about how to do this perfectly so I'm sharing in hope of saving others searching for a complete answer some time: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/detecting-runs-or-streaks-in-your-data